# Find the minimum j-i (i<j) that a[j]>a[i] and b[j]>b[i] in O(N) or O(NlogN)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given 2 arrays a[] and b[] (index start from 1) have the same length (we call N). And you have to find the minimum j-i which 0<i<j<=N and **a[i]<a[j] and b[i]<b[j]**.

**Example:**

INP: N=3, a[]={1,7,3}, b[]={3,6,2}

OUT: 1 (choose i=1, j=2)

**Constraints:**

n<=10^6

**I have only can do in O(N^2) with brute-force but this problem require O(N) or O(NlogN)**

Comment: Please share the constraints..

Comment: in you example a[i] is greater than a[j] and b[i] also greater than b[j]. it shouldn't be the other way around?

Comment: Are you sure O(N) is possible? O(n log n) can be done with a sliding window, but you can use this problem to solve [the element distinctness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem), so O(N) requires restrictions on the input or possibly some kind of hashing.

Comment: @adarsh the only constraints is n<=1000000

Comment: @ZinedineBenkhider i forgot telling that the index started from 1, so a[1] = 1, a[2] =7

Comment: @kcsquared oh, O(NlogN) it's also ok

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-arr-find-the-maximum-j-i-such-that-arrj-arri/amp/ ur que is updated version of this problem... Just store the possible indexes

Comment: @adarsh It is distantly related to that problem; a closer analogue is [all nearest smaller values.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_nearest_smaller_values) Unfortunately there is no way to adapt the O(n) solution for a single array to an O(n) worst case solution for two arrays simultaneously. For the optimal O(n log n) solution, you can use range trees, segment trees, or any dynamic range-minimum query data structure, among other approaches.

Comment: @kcsquared what will be stored in our segments if we are constructing segment tree? Can you please share a brief idea ....i'm stuck right now.... How it will help for 2 arrays?